# How to name capture with multi-line regex from multi-line string

Tags: regex, powershell, multiline

I know how to use named capture on an array of lines but... how do I use named capture on multi-line string?

```
$herestring = @"
Foo
  Bar
    Foo
      Manchu
"@ 

$pattern = [regex]'(?s)(?<Foo>Foo\s+\w+)'
```

This doesn't seem to work for name captures. I can retrieve the match group from the groups collection but not by name.

```
$herestring | Select-String -Pattern $pattern -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches }
```

Now what?

Comment: Now get the groups by name. `$herestring | Select-String -Pattern $pattern -AllMatches | % {$_.Matches } | % { $_.Groups['Foo'].Value }`

Comment: Another way: `$pattern.Matches($herestring) | % {$_.groups['Foo'].value}`

Comment: I was looking into the structure of [ ] and it's not very obvious by only looking into the object's property (Groups) as nothing seems to show there. Digging deeper into the structure of the brackets and it's use, it seems to be accessing a hashtable key's value, is this correct? Hashtable key as in: `$hash["name"]`, but if it was you should be able to write this as well: `$_.Groups.Foo` - but that doesn't work. I'm not sure what kind of structure this is, but it works. Thanks.